# Non-linear Least squares fitting in R

Tags: r, least-squares, curve-fitting, approximation

I want to fit a curve to a set of 3 data points (1,65), (200,70), (800,75) in the form

> $y = \frac{ax}{b+x}$

Using the set of points I have this set of equations

$a-65b = 65$

$200a-70b = 14000$

$800a-75b = 60000$

Re-writing in $Ax = b$ form:

$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & -65 \\
    200 & -70 \\
    800 & -75  \\ 
    \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
    a \\
    b 
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    65 \\
    14000 \\
    60000 
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

This does not have a solution so I want to use least squares fitting. Solving manually for
$A^TAx = A^Tb$,  I finally get:
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
    680001a−74065b \\
    −74065a+14750b
    \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}
    50800065 \\
    −5484225
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

I use the solve function to solve this set of equations, shown below:

```
a <- matrix(c(680001, -74065, -74065, 14750), 2, 2)
b <- c(50800065, -5484225)

solve(a,b)
```

Which gives me the parameters I want. However, my question is about doing this on R without doing any manual calculations. So I want to automate the solving of $A^TAx = A^Tb$.

Comment: Unless you are actually measuring $y(b+x)-ax,$ this procedure is probably not suitable for your data.  That's worth considering before you proceed to automate it.

Comment: What would you recommend? This is the best solution I was able to come up with

Comment: Write a function of $b$ that returns the sum of squares of residuals for the model $y = az + \varepsilon$ where $z = x/(b+x)$ and $\varepsilon$ is the random error.  Find the value of $b$ that minimizes that function and for $a$ use the least-squares coefficient.  I find $\hat b = 0.11608$ and $\hat a = 73.532.$  It fits the point $(1,65)$ *much* better than the solution in the question.  This assumes that essentially all the measurement error occurs in the $y$ values, not the $x$ values, but similar approaches are available when the error is in $x.$